# mysql fulltext index

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I need `MySQL` fulltext search to index something like **207/12.25/07/2012** the database has minimum 2 million rows and growing, so correct indexing is absolutely essential. Please help. Right now it seems that **slashes** and **fullstops** are omitted and only **2012** is indexed.

Comment: What kind of searches do you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FULLTEXT` index can be used to search for words in larger blocks of text. Seeing that your data does not consist of words, wouldn't a normal index work for you? That would make searches for a prefix like `207/12%` fast.

With a normal index searches for a suffix like `%25/07/2012` would require a full table scan. If you are searching for suffixes you can create a column that has the data in reverse, and then index and search that column.

If you are searching for something that lies in the middle, like `%12.25%`, it might make sense to create a `FULLTEXT` index, you just have to [add `.` into the list of "word characters"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) (mysql.com) but apparently that requires compiling MySQL from source.